# How to show the "internal storage" option in an ActionOpenDocument intent by default

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android

I need the user to select a file of a custom filetype that they've dragged onto their android device from windows file explorer, but the internal storage option isn't available by default.

When I launch the intent using this:

```
var libraryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionOpenDocument);
libraryIntent.SetType("application/*");
_activity.StartActivityForResult(libraryIntent, (int)ActivityRequestCode.ImportFeatureCodeLibrary);
```

Android OS (5.1 and 6.0) shows the following screen:

[image]

The user has to know to go to the button in the top right and select the option to show internal file storage:

[image]

They have to click the hamburger again and only then does it show up in the list:

[image]

Is there a way to have this option show up in the list by default, or even better to have the user dropped into the "internal storage" file picker?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: I have shown my code at the top. That's how I create and launch the intent.

Comment: Try removing this line `libraryIntent.SetType("application/*");`

Answer (score 9):

You can add an extra to the `intent` :

```
libraryIntent.PutExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);
```

As far as I know it's an undocumented extra, but it seams to work from API 19 to at least 26

Comment: Works perfectly

Comment: Does not seem to work on API 29 :( IMHO..tested on Pixel 4

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at that library - [Material File Picker](https://github.com/nbsp-team/MaterialFilePicker)
It allows showing a dialog with the specified path using `.withPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile())`.

The whole creation code:

```
new MaterialFilePicker()
    .withActivity(this)
    .withRequestCode(1)
    .withFilter(Pattern.compile(".*\\.txt$")) // Filtering files and directories by file name using regexp
    .withFilterDirectories(true) // Set directories filterable (false by default)
    .withHiddenFiles(true) // Show hidden files and folders
    .withPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile())
    .start();
```

Comment: I should have been clearer, but I'm using Xamarin and C#, which isn't supported by the material file picker library.